# How to Access the online Google dictionary into our Application

Tags: asp.net, google-chrome

I want to create the application in which i can type any word into text box and when i click on "search meaning" it directly connect to google dictionary and give the following out put
1)Type of word ie Adjective or noun
2)pronunciation

can any one please tell me is this possible ?Is google provide such API ? I have searched a lot online but i didn't get any helpfull solution.

Answer (score 0):

Go through this Link hope it will help you to achieve your desired Task.

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/9156/Google-Suggest-like-Dictionary

Comment: Thanks for reply.i want to make a desktop application not web application.any other link for desktop application for achieving the same goal.

Comment: okey then u can try http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/61265/GCIDE-A-Complete-English-Language-Dictionary